# Как можно сверстать подобное?

Tags: css, grid

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main.gallery {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery > .gallery__list {
  margin: 0;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(140px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 140px);
}

.gallery > .gallery__list > li:nth-child(4n) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.gallery > .gallery__list > li:nth-child(8n) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.gallery > .gallery__list > li > figure {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}

.gallery > .gallery__list > li > figure:hover {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.gallery > .gallery__list > li > figure > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="gallery">
      <ul class="gallery__list">
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/1.jpg"
              alt="Juno's Latest Flyby of Jupiter Captures Two Massive Storms"
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="A first look at dunes" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/4.jpg"
              alt="K2-138 6 Planets Artwork (Artist's Illustration) "
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="Small Prominences" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Ezinu Crater" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="Polar Ice" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="Jupiter" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Another Cloudy Day" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/3.jpg"
              alt="South Equatorial Belt Brown Barge Close-up"
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="Jupiter" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Another Cloudy Day" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="Jupiter" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/3.jpg"
              alt="South Equatorial Belt Brown Barge Close-up"
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="Jupiter" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Another Cloudy Day" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/1.jpg"
              alt="Juno's Latest Flyby of Jupiter Captures Two Massive Storms"
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/3.jpg"
              alt="South Equatorial Belt Brown Barge Close-up"
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Another Cloudy Day" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="Jupiter" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img
              src="./img/3.jpg"
              alt="South Equatorial Belt Brown Barge Close-up"
            />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/3.jpg" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Another Cloudy Day" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/3.jpg" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="A first look at dunes" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="Star Gaia 17pbi Seen by Spitzer" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/3.jpg" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" />
          </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="Another Cloudy Day" />
          </figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
Как можно сверстать такое с помощью grid?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "aa aa aa aa ab ab ac ac ad ae af af"
    "aa aa aa aa ab ab ac ac ag ah af af"
    "aa aa aa aa ai ai ak ak ak ak ak ak"
    "aa aa aa aa ai ai ak ak ak ak ak ak"
    "al am an ao ap aq as as at at au av"
    "aw ax ay ay az ba as as at at bb bc"
    "bd bd ay ay be be bf bg bh bh bh bh"
    "bd bd bi bi be be bj bj bh bh bh bh"
    "bk bk bi bi bl bm bj bj bh bh bh bh"
    "bk bk bn bo bp bq br bs bh bh bh bh";
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, white, blue);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.ak {
  aspect-ratio: unset;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div style="grid-area:aa"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ab"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ac"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ad"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ae"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:af"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ag"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ah"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ai"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ak" class="ak"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:al"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:am"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:an"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ao"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ap"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:aq"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:as"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:at"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:au"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:av"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:aw"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ax"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ay"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:az"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:ba"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bb"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bc"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bd"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:be"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bf"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bg"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bh"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bi"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bj"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bk"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bl"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bm"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bn"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bo"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bp"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bq"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:br"></div>
  <div style="grid-area:bs"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить возможность создавать компоненты на React любых размеров

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 8.333vw;
  gap: 2px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.grid-container > div {

    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

  .large {
      grid-area: span 4 / span 4;
    }
  .medium {
    grid-area: span 2 / span 2;
  }
  .small {
    grid-area: span 1 / span 1;
  }
  .half {
    grid-area: span 2 / span 6;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The grid-area Property</h1>

<p>You can use the <em>grid-area</em> property to specify where to place an item.</p>
<p>The syntax is grid-row-start / grid-column-start / grid-row-end / grid-column-end.</p>
<p>Item1 will start on row 2 and column 1, and span 2 rows and 3 columns:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="large">1</div>  <div class="large">1</div>
  <div class="large">1</div>
    <div class="medium">2</div>

  <div class="large">1</div>
  <div class="large">1</div>
  <div class="large">1</div>

  <div class="medium">2</div>  <div class="medium">2</div>
  <div class="medium">2</div>
  <div class="medium">2</div>

  <div class="medium">3</div>  
  <div class="small">4</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>  <div class="small">5</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>

  <div class="large">6</div>
  <div class="medium">7</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>```
````